# Is there a way to get my VS Code to look like Sublime Build 4143. I dont like monoki and ma used to the formatting of build 4143

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, sublimetext3

I would like my vs code to look like this. Is there a way to get it to look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjieA.png)

I tried to find an extension but was not able to.

Comment: what colour theme is that in your screenshot of sublime? note that the default VS Code settings `editor.renderWhitespace` and `editor.roundedSelection` are the closest you'll get with respect to what they do. I don't know of a way to get outlines on the selection. what else are you missing other than just what those two settings and the colour theme setting can achieve?

Comment: what keeps you of writing a theme extension to get that color scheme

Comment: with a few color customizations you can get a close look of what you want the editor to look, choose a theme with a UI you like and change the TextMate scope colors